# Using mkl_set_num_threads with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, intel-mkl

I'm trying to set the number of threads for numpy calculations with `mkl_set_num_threads` like this

```
import numpy
import ctypes
mkl_rt = ctypes.CDLL('libmkl_rt.so')
mkl_rt.mkl_set_num_threads(4)
```

but I keep getting an segmentation fault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00002aaab34d7561 in mkl_set_num_threads__ () from /../libmkl_intel_lp64.so
```

Getting the number of threads is no problem:

```
print mkl_rt.mkl_get_max_threads()
```

How can I get my code working?
Or is there another way to set the number of threads at runtime?

Comment: When I had the Enthought Python distribution I could `import mkl` as a module. I wonder what happened behind the scenes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ophion led me the right way. Despite the documentation, one have to transfer the parameter of `mkl_set_num_thread` by reference.

Now I have defined to functions, for getting and setting the threads

```
import numpy
import ctypes
mkl_rt = ctypes.CDLL('libmkl_rt.so')
mkl_get_max_threads = mkl_rt.mkl_get_max_threads
def mkl_set_num_threads(cores):
    mkl_rt.mkl_set_num_threads(ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int(cores)))

mkl_set_num_threads(4)
print mkl_get_max_threads() # says 4
```

and they work as expected.

Edit: according to Rufflewind, the names of the C-Functions are written in capital-case, which expect parameters by value:

```
import ctypes

mkl_rt = ctypes.CDLL('libmkl_rt.so')
mkl_set_num_threads = mkl_rt.MKL_Set_Num_Threads
mkl_get_max_threads = mkl_rt.MKL_Get_Max_Threads
```

Answer (score 8):

Long story short, use `MKL_Set_Num_Threads` and its CamelCased friends when calling MKL from Python.  The same applies to C if you don't `#include <mkl.h>`.

---

The [MKL documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/471134) seems to suggest that the correct type signature in C is:

```c
void mkl_set_num_threads(int nt);
```

Okay, let's try a minimal program then:

```c
void mkl_set_num_threads(int);
int main(void) {
    mkl_set_num_threads(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with GCC and *boom*, `Segmentation fault` again.  So it seems the problem isn't restricted to Python.

Running it through a debugger (GDB) reveals:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000… in mkl_set_num_threads_ ()
   from /…/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so
```

Wait a second, `mkl_set_num_threads_`??  That's the *Fortran version* of `mkl_set_num_threads`!  How did we end up calling the Fortran version?  (Keep in mind that Fortran's calling convention requires arguments to be passed as *pointers* rather than by value.)

It turns out the documentation was a complete façade.  If you actually inspect the header files for the recent versions of MKL, you will find this cute little definition:

```c
void    MKL_Set_Num_Threads(int nth);
#define mkl_set_num_threads         MKL_Set_Num_Threads
```

… and now everything makes sense!  The correct function do call (for C code) is `MKL_Set_Num_Threads`, not `mkl_set_num_threads`.  Inspecting the symbol table reveals that there are actually *four different variants* defined:

```
nm -D /…/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so | grep -i mkl_set_num_threads
00000000000e3060 T MKL_SET_NUM_THREADS
…
00000000000e30b0 T MKL_Set_Num_Threads
…
00000000000e3060 T mkl_set_num_threads
00000000000e3060 T mkl_set_num_threads_
…
```

Why did Intel put in four different variants of one function despite there being only C and Fortran variants in the documentation?  I don't know for certain, but I suspect it's for compatibility with different Fortran compilers.  You see, Fortran calling convention is not standardized.  Different compilers will [mangle the names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_Fortran) of the functions differently:

- some use upper case,
- some use lower case with a trailing underscore, and
- some use lower case with no decoration at all.

There may even be other ways that I'm not aware of.  This trick allows the MKL library to be used with *most Fortran compilers* without any modification, the downside being that C functions need to be "mangled" to make room for the 3 variants of the Fortran calling convention.

Answer (score 2):

For people looking for a cross platform and packaged solution, note that we have recently released [`threadpoolctl`](https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl), a module to limit the number of threads used in C-level threadpools called by python (`OpenBLAS`, `OpenMP` and `MKL`). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56443185/2642845) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

For people looking for the complete solution, you can use a context manager:

```py
import ctypes


class MKLThreads(object):
    _mkl_rt = None

    @classmethod
    def _mkl(cls):
        if cls._mkl_rt is None:
            try:
                cls._mkl_rt = ctypes.CDLL('libmkl_rt.so')
            except OSError:
                cls._mkl_rt = ctypes.CDLL('mkl_rt.dll')
        return cls._mkl_rt

    @classmethod
    def get_max_threads(cls):
        return cls._mkl().mkl_get_max_threads()

    @classmethod
    def set_num_threads(cls, n):
        assert type(n) == int
        cls._mkl().mkl_set_num_threads(ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int(n)))

    def __init__(self, num_threads):
        self._n = num_threads
        self._saved_n = self.get_max_threads()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.set_num_threads(self._n)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.set_num_threads(self._saved_n)
```

Then use it like:

```py
with MKLThreads(2):
    # do some stuff on two cores
    pass
```

Or just manipulating configuration by calling following functions:

```py
# Example
MKLThreads.set_num_threads(3)
print(MKLThreads.get_max_threads())
```

Code is also available in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/technic/80e8d95858b187cd8ff8677bd5cc0fbb).