# Set max number of threads at runtime on numpy/openblas

Tags: python, numpy, blas, openblas

I'd like to know if it's possible to change at (Python) runtime the maximum number of threads used by OpenBLAS behind numpy?

I know it's possible to set it before running the interpreter through the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, but I'd like to change it at runtime.

Typically, when using MKL instead of OpenBLAS, it is possible:

```
import mkl
mkl.set_num_threads(n)
```

Comment: You can try calling the `openblas_set_num_threads` function using the `ctypes` module. Similar to [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28283112/2379410)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this by calling the `openblas_set_num_threads` function using `ctypes`. I often find myself wanting to do this, so I wrote a little context manager:

```
import contextlib
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library

# Prioritize hand-compiled OpenBLAS library over version in /usr/lib/
# from Ubuntu repos
try_paths = ['/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so',
             '/lib/libopenblas.so',
             '/usr/lib/libopenblas.so.0',
             find_library('openblas')]
openblas_lib = None
for libpath in try_paths:
    try:
        openblas_lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libpath)
        break
    except OSError:
        continue
if openblas_lib is None:
    raise EnvironmentError('Could not locate an OpenBLAS shared library', 2)


def set_num_threads(n):
    """Set the current number of threads used by the OpenBLAS server."""
    openblas_lib.openblas_set_num_threads(int(n))


# At the time of writing these symbols were very new:
# https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/commit/65a847c
try:
    openblas_lib.openblas_get_num_threads()
    def get_num_threads():
        """Get the current number of threads used by the OpenBLAS server."""
        return openblas_lib.openblas_get_num_threads()
except AttributeError:
    def get_num_threads():
        """Dummy function (symbol not present in %s), returns -1."""
        return -1
    pass

try:
    openblas_lib.openblas_get_num_procs()
    def get_num_procs():
        """Get the total number of physical processors"""
        return openblas_lib.openblas_get_num_procs()
except AttributeError:
    def get_num_procs():
        """Dummy function (symbol not present), returns -1."""
        return -1
    pass


@contextlib.contextmanager
def num_threads(n):
    """Temporarily changes the number of OpenBLAS threads.

    Example usage:

        print("Before: {}".format(get_num_threads()))
        with num_threads(n):
            print("In thread context: {}".format(get_num_threads()))
        print("After: {}".format(get_num_threads()))
    """
    old_n = get_num_threads()
    set_num_threads(n)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        set_num_threads(old_n)
```

You can use it like this:

```
with num_threads(8):
    np.dot(x, y)
```

As mentioned in the comments, `openblas_get_num_threads` and `openblas_get_num_procs` were very new features at the time of writing, and might therefore not be available unless you compiled OpenBLAS from the latest version of the source code.

Comment: note that as of v0.2.14 pthread openblas_get_num_procs does not account for affinity so it can lead to oversubscription when the number of usable cpus is restricted (e.g. in containers), use len(os.sched_getaffinity(0)) (python >= 3.3) instead

Comment: @jtaylor     Great idea, I'm thinking, if it is possible to change the thread binding at run time. For example, I want some to be done with 8 threads at 1st CPU socket, and others to be done with single thread at 2nd CPU socket

Answer (score 14):

We recently developed [`threadpoolctl`](https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl), a cross platform package to do control the number of threads used in calls to C-level thread-pools in python. It works similarly to the answer by @ali_m but detects automatically the libraries that needs to be limited by looping through all loaded libraries. It also comes with introspection APIs.

This package can be installed using `pip install threadpoolctl` and come with a context manager that allow you to control the number of threads used by packages such as `numpy`:

```py
from threadpoolctl import threadpool_limits
import numpy as np


with threadpool_limits(limits=1, user_api='blas'):
    # In this block, calls to blas implementation (like openblas or MKL)
    # will be limited to use only one thread. They can thus be used jointly
    # with thread-parallelism.
    a = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)
    a_squared = a @ a
```

you can also have finer control on different threadpools (such as differenciating `blas` from `openmp` calls).

**Note:** this package is still in development and any feedback is welcomed.