# How can I have a finer control on number of threads used for each BLAS kernel call on CPU?

Tags: multithreading, openmp, intel-mkl, openblas

I am writing an OpenMP code calling different BLAS kernels, mostly DGEMMs with different sizes, in different threads. To maximize performance I want to have control over the number of threads I am calling for each BLAS.
It seems that it is a very obvious basic need though it is very hard to do.

OpenBLAS has a function `openblas_set_num_threads(int n)`, in the README file of OpenBLAS code it is described that

> These are only used once at library initialization, and are not available for
> fine-tuning thread numbers in individual BLAS calls.

So I guess I cannot use this function in OpenBLAS.

MKL has a function `mkl_set_num_threads_local(int nt)` which seems to be the answer of my question just when I am using MKL.

Is there a way to be able to tune number of threads  for each BLAS call regardless of library I am using? (the ideal  choice)
If not, is it just MKL that let me tune number of threads?

Comment: Did you tried use openblas_set_num_threads nevertheless? I don't really understand the meaning of the sentence in README, but It would be puzzling to have this function and not be able to use it during the runtime.This https://stackoverflow.com/a/29582987/5769463  suggest that the function works as you would like to use it.

Comment: I tried using it. I am not sure myself, but it seems that it is very different than the mkl one.